# Updating a Matrix Determinant After Row Replacement

Tags: matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

Given a square matrix **A** (of varying dimension), I am looking for an efficient algorithm or formula to recompute the determinant of that matrix if a row **i** is replaced with different values.

For example, given the matrix A:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\\\
4 & 5 & 6 \\\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}$$

And replacing the second row (i = 2), as a new matrix B:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\\\
10 & 11 & 12 \\\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{bmatrix}$$

I would like to efficiently recalculate the determinant, without performing another full determinant computation for **B**. The algorithm I am currently using is based on the [Wikipedia pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Pseudocode) for Gaussian elimination with pivoting. After reducing the matrix to row echelon form, the determinant is obtained by multiplying the diagonals. While essential for numerical stability, the pivoting poses an issue since I cannot "jump back into" the algorithm at row **i**.

If someone is familiar with a property of matrices that could help saving on computation here or knows of a better way to achieve this without recalculating everything from scratch for **B** it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\det\pmatrix{1&2&3\cr a&b&c\cr7&8&9\cr}=-a\det\pmatrix{2&3\cr8&9\cr}+b\det\pmatrix{1&3\cr7&9\cr}-c\det\pmatrix{1&2\cr7&8\cr}=6a-12b+6c
$$
so all you have to do is precompute a few smaller determinants and then you're set to swiftly handle any change in a row.

Comment: of course this is only applicable if he always change the same row.

Comment: @Rezha, sure, but if any one row gets changed several times without the other rows changing, then this method could be the quickest.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you! As RezhaAdrianTanuharja pointed out it will only work if we assume the row does not change. In this particular case **i** (the row) should be variable. If **i** does indeed change, I am not sure how it could be adopted to account for that, with the goal of improving efficiency.

Comment: If row changes are infrequent, then each time a new row is chosen, you adapt this method to that row. If row changes are frequent, I'm not sure there is any efficient way, as you're essentially dealing with a completely different matrix after a few changes.